# What problems can I expect using deadsnakes ppa as my primary python3 instance to get python3 to ref python3,7?

Tags: 16.04, python3

As the title states, what problems should one expect.  I've seen a few, and I'll note them in the self-answer, but if you've seen any others, I don't think this has been asked/inventoried before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove the python3 symlink and link it to python3.7, you can expect some oddities.

You won't have python3 -m pip until you reinstall `python3-pip` in some way.  Doing it through the package manager works.

apt_python won't be found, and reinstalling from the package doesn't work, but copying the .so file with a rename does:
`sudo cp /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt_pkg.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so /usr/lib/python3.7/apt_pkg.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`

gdbm won't be found, if you have some need for it, but copying the .so again works:
`sudo ln -s /usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload/_gdbm.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so /usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_gdbm.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`