# Unable to open terminal but i can open it through a folder

Tags: command-line

As the title says. I cant open a terminal via the "normal" way (or by search), but i can open it through a folder. There is a serious mess i guess with python, but i dont know how to fix it. Any help ?

This is the message showing when i open a terminal through a folder:

```
bash: /home/app/Desktop/apps/miniconda3/bin/conda: /home/app/Desktop/apps/miniconda3/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/dbm/gnu.py", line 4, in <module>
    from _gdbm import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_gdbm'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/CommandNotFound.py", line 7, in <module>
    import dbm.gnu as gdbm
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/dbm/gnu.py", line 6, in <module>
    raise ImportError(str(msg) + ', please install the python3-gdbm package')
ImportError: No module named '_gdbm', please install the python3-gdbm package

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 27, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.util import crash_guard
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.CommandNotFound import CommandNotFound
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/CommandNotFound.py", line 9, in <module>
    import gdbm
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gdbm'
```

when i try to install python-gdbm:

```
W: Target Packages (Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:36 and /etc/apt/sources.list:38
W: Target Translations (en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:36 and /etc/apt/sources.list:38
W: Target Translations (en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:36 and /etc/apt/sources.list:38
E: The repository 'http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: Target Packages (Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:36 and /etc/apt/sources.list:38
W: Target Translations (en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:36 and /etc/apt/sources.list:38
W: Target Translations (en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:36 and /etc/apt/sources.list:38
```

[image: source-list-numbered]

i # the 38th line, then sudo update, still cant open it

output

```
basemount.list                                mono-official-stable.list.save
basemount.list.save                           noobslab-ubuntu-themes-xenial.list
basespacefs.list                              noobslab-ubuntu-themes-xenial.list.save
basespacefs.list.save                         notepadqq-team-ubuntu-notepadqq-xenial.list
cuda-10-0-local-10.0.130-410.48.list          notepadqq-team-ubuntu-notepadqq-xenial.list.save
cuda-10-0-local-10.0.130-410.48.list.save     opera-stable.list
cuda.list                                     opera-stable.list.save
cuda.list.save                                teamviewer.list
deadsnakes-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list             tvinternal.list
deadsnakes-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list.save        ubuntugis-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list
getdeb.list                                   ubuntugis-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list.save
getdeb.list.save                              ubuntugis-ubuntu-ubuntugis-unstable-xenial.list
google-chrome.list                            ubuntugis-ubuntu-ubuntugis-unstable-xenial.list.save
google-chrome.list.save                       ubuntu-x-swat-ubuntu-updates-xenial.list
graphics-drivers-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list       ubuntu-x-swat-ubuntu-updates-xenial.list.save
graphics-drivers-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list.save  vscode.list
jonathonf-ubuntu-gcc-7_1-xenial.list          vscode.list.save
marutter-ubuntu-rdev-xenial.list              webupd8team-ubuntu-java-xenial.list
marutter-ubuntu-rdev-xenial.list.save         webupd8team-ubuntu-java-xenial.list.save
marutter-ubuntu-rrutter3_5-xenial.list        webupd8team-ubuntu-y-ppa-manager-xenial.list
marutter-ubuntu-rrutter3_5-xenial.list.save   webupd8team-ubuntu-y-ppa-manager-xenial.list.save
```

sudo dpkg -S 'gdbm'

```
libgdbm-dev: /usr/share/man/man3/gdbm_error.3.gz
libgdbm-dev: /usr/include/gdbm.h
libgdbm-dev: /usr/share/man/man3/gdbm.3.gz
libgdbm-dev: /usr/include/gdbm-ndbm.h
libgdbm3:amd64: /usr/share/doc/libgdbm3
libgdbm-dev: /usr/share/doc/libgdbm-dev/README.gz
libgdbm3:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdbm_compat.so.3.0.0
python3-gdbm:amd64: /usr/share/doc/python3-gdbm/copyright
libgdbm-dev: /usr/share/man/man3/gdbm_delete.3.gz
libgdbm-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdbm_compat.so
python3-gdbm:amd64: /usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload/_gdbm.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
libgdbm-dev: /usr/share/man/man3/gdbm_setopt.3.gz
libgdbm3:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdbm.so.3
libgdbm-dev: /usr/share/man/man3/gdbm_open.3.gz
libgdbm3:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdbm_compat.so.3
libruby2.3:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.3.0/gdbm.so
python3-gdbm:amd64: /usr/share/doc/python3-gdbm/changelog.Debian.gz
libgdbm-dev: /usr/share/doc/libgdbm-dev
libgdbm-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdbm.a
libgdbm-dev: /usr/share/man/man3/gdbm_reorganize.3.gz
libgdbm-dev: /usr/share/doc/libgdbm-dev/changelog.Debian.gz
libgdbm-dev: /usr/share/man/man3/gdbm_sync.3.gz
libgdbm-dev: /usr/share/man/man3/gdbm_close.3.gz
libgdbm-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdbm_compat.a
libgdbm-dev: /usr/share/man/man3/gdbm_firstkey.3.gz
libgdbm-dev: /usr/share/info/gdbm.info.gz
libgdbm-dev: /usr/share/doc/libgdbm-dev/copyright
python3-gdbm:amd64: /usr/share/doc/python3-gdbm/README.Debian
libgdbm-dev: /usr/share/doc/libgdbm-dev/NEWS.gz
libgdbm-dev: /usr/share/man/man3/gdbm_errno.3.gz
libgdbm3:amd64: /usr/share/doc/libgdbm3/changelog.Debian.gz
libgdbm3:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdbm.so.3.0.0
libgdbm-dev: /usr/share/man/man3/gdbm_nextkey.3.gz
libgdbm-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdbm.so
libgdbm3:amd64: /usr/share/doc/libgdbm3/copyright
libgdbm-dev: /usr/share/man/man3/gdbm_fetch.3.gz
libgdbm-dev: /usr/share/man/man3/gdbm_store.3.gz
python3-gdbm:amd64: /usr/share/doc/python3-gdbm
libgdbm-dev: /usr/share/man/man3/gdbm_strerror.3.gz
libgdbm-dev: /usr/share/man/man3/gdbm_exists.3.gz


    libgdbm-dev: /usr/share/man/man3/gdbm_error.3.gz
    libgdbm-dev: /usr/include/gdbm.h
    libgdbm-dev: /usr/share/man/man3/gdbm.3.gz
    libgdbm-dev: /usr/include/gdbm-ndbm.h
    libgdbm3:amd64: /usr/share/doc/libgdbm3
    libgdbm-dev: /usr/share/doc/libgdbm-dev/README.gz
    libgdbm3:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdbm_compat.so.3.0.0
    python3-gdbm:amd64: /usr/share/doc/python3-gdbm/copyright
    libgdbm-dev: /usr/share/man/man3/gdbm_delete.3.gz
    libgdbm-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdbm_compat.so
    python3-gdbm:amd64: /usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload/_gdbm.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
    libgdbm-dev: /usr/share/man/man3/gdbm_setopt.3.gz
    libgdbm3:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdbm.so.3
    libgdbm-dev: /usr/share/man/man3/gdbm_open.3.gz
    libgdbm3:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdbm_compat.so.3
    libruby2.3:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.3.0/gdbm.so
    python3-gdbm:amd64: /usr/share/doc/python3-gdbm/changelog.Debian.gz
    libgdbm-dev: /usr/share/doc/libgdbm-dev
    libgdbm-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdbm.a
    libgdbm-dev: /usr/share/man/man3/gdbm_reorganize.3.gz
    libgdbm-dev: /usr/share/doc/libgdbm-dev/changelog.Debian.gz
    libgdbm-dev: /usr/share/man/man3/gdbm_sync.3.gz
    libgdbm-dev: /usr/share/man/man3/gdbm_close.3.gz
    libgdbm-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdbm_compat.a
    libgdbm-dev: /usr/share/man/man3/gdbm_firstkey.3.gz
    libgdbm-dev: /usr/share/info/gdbm.info.gz
    libgdbm-dev: /usr/share/doc/libgdbm-dev/copyright
    python3-gdbm:amd64: /usr/share/doc/python3-gdbm/README.Debian
    libgdbm-dev: /usr/share/doc/libgdbm-dev/NEWS.gz
    libgdbm-dev: /usr/share/man/man3/gdbm_errno.3.gz
    libgdbm3:amd64: /usr/share/doc/libgdbm3/changelog.Debian.gz
    libgdbm3:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdbm.so.3.0.0
    libgdbm-dev: /usr/share/man/man3/gdbm_nextkey.3.gz
    libgdbm-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdbm.so
    libgdbm3:amd64: /usr/share/doc/libgdbm3/copyright
    libgdbm-dev: /usr/share/man/man3/gdbm_fetch.3.gz
    libgdbm-dev: /usr/share/man/man3/gdbm_store.3.gz
    python3-gdbm:amd64: /usr/share/doc/python3-gdbm
    libgdbm-dev: /usr/share/man/man3/gdbm_strerror.3.gz
    libgdbm-dev: /usr/share/man/man3/gdbm_exists.3.gz
```

Comment: You could try to install python3-gdbm with `sudo apt update && sudo apt-get install python3-gdbm` as the log suggests.

Comment: Also you could give reinstalling the command-not-found package a try: https://askubuntu.com/a/1147372/1037709

Comment: @starkus check the edit on 1st post

Comment: You would need to edit your sources.list with `sudoedit /etc/apt/sources.list`. Can you post a picture, or post the content of it? Seems like you need to disable the getdeb repository.

Comment: @starkus done, edited original post

Comment: You could try to comment out line 36, or 38 in your sources.list with # in the beginning of the line. Not sure if you need the architecture specification in line 36. So I would try line 38 and `sudo apt update` after saving the file.

Comment: @starkus this one : deb-src [arch=i386,amd64] https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/ ? and how do i save the file after editing?

Comment: I cannot count the lines using the picture you posted. Try `sudo nano -l /etc/apt/sources.list` to get a numbered list. You may save with `Ctrl` + `o`. After saving, you can exit nano with `Ctrl` + `x`.

Comment: The server content of one of your sources.list entries equals with another one on your list... That's why the error occurred. And you need to comment out that one.

Comment: this command sudo nano -l /etc/apt/sources.list, doent work. nano is installed

Comment: How about `sudo cat -n /etc/apt/sources.list`? Or can you open it with gedit or pluma and activate line numbering?

Comment: @starkus edited original post. Still cant open it

Comment: you would need `sudo apt update`, not sudo update, after you've saved the file.

Comment: yes i ve done that. E: The repository 'http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get purge getdeb-repository` and `sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.*`, or comment it out in the same way, but using the etc/apt/sources.list.d/ folder. Not sure how the entry is named. You could post the output of `ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d/` to analyze.

Comment: @starkus sudo apt update works now. Still cant open a terminal. I did : sudo apt-get purge getdeb-repository and sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.* ,  check original post

Comment: Okay, now you need to start at the beginning of our conversation. But try to not use `sudo aptitude purge ~c command-not-found` because I'm not sure about it maybe removing more config files as needed. (The commands from the link). You could maybe give `sudo apt-get install -f && sudo dpkg --configure -a` a try first.

Comment: still doesnt open...

Comment: Does opening it with a debugging option give you any hints? Just like `gnome-terminal --gdk-debug=all`

Comment: And what does `sudo dpkg -S  'gdbm'` tell you?

Comment: @starkus updated original post with output

Comment: `python3-gdbm:amd64: /usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload/_gdbm.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` - I think that needs to be 3.7.  Tried to reconfigure, purge and reinstall it?

Comment: I found a thread that could maybe solve your issues... --> https://askubuntu.com/q/1090079/1037709

Comment: Got it fixed? `sudo apt-cache policy python3-gdbm` would show you if you installed it from a non default source like `deadsnakes-ubuntu-ppa` and `sudo apt-cache show python3-gdbm` shows some other info's, like dependencies and stuff...